Regular Expression does not split semicolon separated string in C# if first match is empty
I want to split a semicolon-separated test string with a regular expression in C# .NET.
I know I could use for this example the string split method but the pattern and input string is a bit more complicated and I want to keep it simple.
This is the pattern:
string pattern = @"(?:^|;)(([^;]*|)(?=;|$))";`

And this is the test string:
string input = @"text1;text2;text3;;text5";

The match results are:
[0] text1
[1] text2
[2] text3
[3] 
[4] text5

And this looks good to me!
But if I change the test string to:
string input = @";text2;text3;;text5";

then I get these results:
[0] 
[1] text3
[2] 
[3] text5

But I was expecting
[0] 
[1] text2
[2] text3
[3] 
[4] text5

So my questions are:
Why is it a problem for the .NET engine when the test string starts with an empty string?
Even if the engine cannot return the first empty string, where is text2? Or is the first match the empty string?
And what do I have to change that it also works in C#?
You can test it on Regex101. And if you switch to PCRE2 instead of .NET 7 you get the expected results.

Seems to work fine if you omit the non-capture group and replace it with a lookbehind:
(?<=^|;)([^;]*)(?=;|$)


This works for me!
But I dont understand why my pattern is not working.

@Matzy Just to mention, also the negation without alternation could work: (?<![^;])([^;]*)(?![^;]) - Regex engines are working differently, which is not necessarily an "issue". For example matching string ; using (?:^|;) .NET regex is satisfied with the left option (start of the string) while in PCRE you get two matches. If you changed order of the options to (?:;|^) both match ;. Best to list your options in sequence of priority from left to right.
